# What do we think about Father's Day?

Tags: halacha, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, non-jewish-holidays, secular-culture

Is there anything wrong with celebrating Father's Day? (Perhaps implying that you only need to give your father special attention one day a year?)

Is there anything right with celebrating Father's Day? (Perhaps ensures that at least one day a year you *will* give your father special attention?)

Do any contemporary poskim discuss this?

Comment: And chukas hagoyim is not part of your question?

Comment: @Nafkamina I left it open-ended and offered one possibility for each side.  If you can find idolatrous roots for Father's day, or some other reason it should be a problem, fire away.

Comment: I assume this question goes for mothers' day as well?

Comment: Kibbud Av v'Em is not restricted to one day!

Comment: @bondonk Yeah, father's day just happened to be yesterday.  And I'm not sure what your exclamatory remark was meant to add - that was the point of my first perhaps.

Comment: In Israel they have "Yom Aim" (Mother's Day), but they also have Chodesh Av.

Comment: @YEZ Actually father's day does have roots in other religions. Father's Day was founded by the YMCA in 1909. It looks to be a custom of the goyim. However does it lose its status of avodah zara nowadays in that it is commercialized?

Comment: http://www.torahmusings.com/2012/02/valentines-day-and-jewish-law/

Comment: Now that it's after Father's Day, I'll tell you that I spent my day in hours of traffic driving my miece to the airport. My son, saw that I sacrificed my time. energy and frazzled myself all to do a good cause for his cousin. That impressed him, and he honored me by reminding me what a great dad he is. Sometimes, when you sacrifice for others, you automatically get the best present that speaks for itself. You don't need a special day of the year for that!

Comment: @armoose can you kindly explain to those of us who don't know what the universal custom of Father's Day is that we shouldn't be doing?  If something has no particular mode of celebration I'm not sure if "chukas hagoyim" can apply to it.  "Don't feel nice towards your father on this day" seems a bit out of the chukos hagoyim ballpark.  And I'm not familiar with the YMCA founding of it, but was it even done on religious grounds, or just happened to be by a religious organization? (note that YMCA does not typically establish Christian policy - the Church gets that right usually)

Comment: And does anyone want to give an explanation for the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

Will Rogers commented on Mother's Day:

> It's a nice idea and all, but whoever came up with it must have had a hurting conscience.

I can't see Father's Day as having blatantly pagan origins. If having one day a year to focus on recognizing your father is meaningful for your father (especially if he's expecting some recognition), then by all means do it. If neither he nor you really cares about it, then there's no need.

Look, today we like to turn values into simple actions that can be ceremonialized and commercialized. You bought dad a plasma TV on Father's Day? *Yotzei*. The true meaning of honoring your parents is complex; the medrish says that you could feed your elderly father the finest of aged steaks while dishonoring him ("it's food dad, just eat it, old man. I've got take this phone call now."); or give him heavy labor at the millstone while honoring him ("between the two of us, one needed to work the mill, and the other needed to be drafted into the army; I'm so sorry dad, I think this is the least-difficult thing I could do to you.") It's all about the attitude.

And from the father's perspective, well, Judaism expects men to civilize themselves and shoulder the responsibility of being an involved parent. If it makes you feel better that there's one day a year when everyone publicly gives you a salute for it, then fine. Hey the Talmud says you don't always have to have perfect motivations for doing the right thing.

I'll tell you how I was taught to observe Father's Day: my father would remind me to call my grandfather (*his* father) and wish him a Happy Father's Day.